# Getting errors installing Strapi

Tags: strapi

Hell guys,
I am trying to install Strapi for my backend, but getting this error:

```js
error strapi-generate-new@3.5.4: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=10.16.0 <=14.x.x". Got "15.9.0"
error Found incompatible module.
```

Any pointers how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Strapi won't run on NodeJS odd numbered versions - which are for developers. You are probably using the 15.14.0, so you have to change to the latest LTS (14.16.1).

To change it, you should use nvm (or node version manager). You can change temporarily with `nvm use 14.16.1` or for good (which I recommend) with `nvm alias default 14.16.1`